# Append new information not repeated in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to transfer information of a file ('a.txt') to other('b.txt'), but in the file 'a.txt' there are information repeated and I want a file ('b.txt') with info no repeated. 
The information is repeated if there are the same 'id', you can see in a.txt: 'name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:xxxxxxxxxxxxx,id:xxxxxxxxxxx,etc
name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:xxxxxxxxxxxxx,id:xxxxxxxxxxx,etc
name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:xxxxxxxxxxxxx,id:xxxxxxxxxxx,etc'

I try to do this, but I have an error (unhashable type:list) in 'if id not in user_id:':

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f:

   user_id=set()
   user=[] 

   for line in f.readlines(): 
      id=[s[5:-1] for s in f.split() if s.startswith("id")] 


       if id not in user_id:
           user_id.add(id)
           user.append(line)

   with open('b.txt', 'a') as f:
       f.writelines(user)
```

So I want to know if there are an other option to transfer the info to other file or how to solve the error. Thank you!

Comment: Split is a `str` method, that's why is not working. The information repeated that you mention, what is repeated? Words, full lines? If you provide this (you don't have to provide the actual info), maybe we can provide a better answer.

Comment: Please add a few lines of your data.

Comment: I have a new error now. I edited the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.split()` operates on the file while you already process the file by its `f.readlines()` line-wise.

You should look for your `id:` inside the `line` you are currently handling:

```
t = """name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:xxxxxxxxxxxxx,id:1xxxxxxxxxxx
name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:xxxxxxxxxxxxx,id:2xxxxxxxxxxx
name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:xxxxxxxxxxxxx,id:3xxxxxxxxxxx, etc
name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:nnnnnnnxxxxxx,id:1xxxxxxxxxxx
name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:nnnnnnnnxxxxx,id:2xxxxxxxxxxx
name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:nnnnnnnnxxxxx,id:3xxxxxxxxxxx"""

allLines = t.split("\n")     # same as f.readlines() gives you

data = {}   #  dictionary to hold id as key and line as value
for line in allLines:        # instead of f.readlines(): for the sake of demonstration
    idPos = line.find("id:")      # id: - position
    colPos = line.find(",",idPos) # , after id:, -1 if nothing in
    if idPos > -1:
        id = line[idPos+3: colPos if colPos > -1 else None] # slice the id
    data.setdefault(id,line) # creates key with line if not existent, else does nothing

for l in data:
    print(data[l])
```

Using a dict to store Id/Linecontent will mess up the order of your file, if that is important, use a list as you did in your approach.

Output:

```
name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:xxxxxxxxxxxxx,id:1xxxxxxxxxxx
name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:xxxxxxxxxxxxx,id:2xxxxxxxxxxx
name:xxxxxxxxx,surnames:xxxxxxxxxxxxx,id:3xxxxxxxxxxx, etc
```

Answer (score 4):

You are splitting the wrong variable. It should be line instead of f (f is a file and line is the line in the file, hope that makes sense). Also, I don't think you need .readlines() method here.

So just change:

```
for line in f:
    id=[s[5:-1] for s in line.split() if s.startswith("id")]
```